# Open another window on clicking OK button of Alert in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, alert, eventhandler

```
private void showAlert(Alert.AlertType alertType, Window owner, String title, String message) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(alertType);
        alert.setTitle(title);
        alert.setHeaderText(null);
        alert.setContentText(message);
        alert.initOwner(owner);
        //alert.show();

        Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
        if ((result.isPresent()) && (result.get() == ButtonType.OK))
        {
            System.out.println("ALL OK..!");
            //Open another window on clicking the OK button

        }
    }
```

On this particular section, on clicking OK button, I want to open another window.
Usually Button type is used for which an event can be defined by

```
buttonName.setOnAction( event -> {
      //Action to do
    } );
```

Now how do I define this OK as a button Type?

Comment: Actually all `Alert` except the ones with `alertType = AlertType.NONE` contain a `OK` button. Therefore you can just do `if (result.orElse(null) == ButtonType.OK) { /* action to do */ }`

Comment: Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
        if ((result.isPresent()) && (result.get() == ButtonType.OK))
        {
         Button okButton = (Button) alert.getDialogPane().lookupButton(ButtonType.OK);
         okButton.setOnAction(e ->
         {
          Stage menuStage = new Stage();
          Main1 menu = new Main1();
   menu.start(menuStage);
   menuStage.show();          
         });
        }

Comment: Why do you want to register a handler just ***after the dialog has been closed*** and you know `OK` was clicked??? `result` contains the `ButtonType` of the button clicked and `showAndWait` returns after the `Alert` is closed. This means you should just put the logic for opening the new window in the if body...